# In Bazel, with a `configure_make` rule, how can you deliver `.la` files?

Tags: makefile, bazel, bazel-cpp

Still working on a rule building `xmlsec1`, I'm trying to define `.la` files to be part of my build artifacts:

```
configure_make(
    name="xmlsec1",
    lib_name="xmlsec1",
    lib_source=":all_srcs",
    configure_command="configure",
    configure_in_place=True,
    deps=["@openssl"],
    out_binaries=["xmlsec1"],
    out_shared_libs=[
        "libxmlsec1.so",
        "libxmlsec1-openssl.so",
        "libxmlsec1-openssl.la",
    ],
    targets=["install"],
)
```

But Bazel doesn't seem to like that - listing both, the `.so` and `.la` file Bazel complains `Can not have libraries with the same name in the same category`. Listing the `.la` file alone uncovers Bazel doesn't even like the extensions:
`Error in create_library_to_link: 'libxmlsec1-openssl.la' does not have any of the allowed extensions .so, .dylib or .dll`

The [documentation](https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_foreign_cc/main/configure_make.html) doesn't seem to cover this use case. And while there is a `out_data_dirs` (which seemingly allows to export files of arbitrary type) option, you can't list single files, only directories..

With `configure_make`, isn't there a way to let build artifacts contain arbitrary files, or `.la` files in particular?

Answer (score 1):

Not an 'answer' but since question got upvoted here is what's working for me:

```py
configure_make(
    name="xmlsec1",

    ...

    out_binaries=["xmlsec1"],

    # Looks like Bazel doesn't know .la files, but we need them.
    #  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75282435
    # So instead of listing library files explicitly we just deliver the
    # whole `lib` folder, containing shared and dynamic libraries as well as
    # .la files
    # Note that we list the dynamic libraries anyway, in order to fail if they
    # for any reason can't be built
    out_shared_libs=[
        "libxmlsec1.so",
        "libxmlsec1.so.1",
        "libxmlsec1-openssl.so",
        "libxmlsec1-openssl.so.1",
    ],

    out_data_dirs=["lib"],

    targets=["install"],
)
```

Comment: Any chance of publishing your full setup for this project on something like github?

Comment: Actually it already is: https://github.com/Checkmk/checkmk/tree/master/omd/packages/xmlsec1. However there are caveats - this project is not ready to be built outside corporate CI and I would strongly suggest to also look into different ways to do it since the current state is just the outcome of a long struggle forcing Bazel into an existing project with lots of build magic. Current approach (yet not implemented for `xmlsec1`) is to provide a different toolchain for `foreign_cc` which better fit's our needs (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75404171/1668622) (Maybe ask James from the answer?).

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I don't think I can use foreign_cc but wonderful to have an example to look at!