# Why does Bazel's foreign_cc rules dereference symlinks in the output? How can I change this?

Tags: bazel, symlink, foreign-cc

I currently into "migrating" some third party dependency projects (typically old style `configure`/`make` based) to Bazel using it's [`foreign_cc` rules](https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_foreign_cc/main/configure_make.html).

One goal is to have identical output compared to before the migration, and among some attributes like permissions and `RPATH` I'm still struggling with symlinks being de-referenced seemingly unconditionally.
So instead of `libfoo.so -> libfoo.so.3`, `libfoo.so.3 -> libfoo.so.3.14` I'll always get three files now.

Inspecting the generated `bazel-bin/external/foo/foo_foreign_cc/build_script.sh` the last commands contain two invocations of `cp -L` with no variables modifying the behavior:

```
[configure command]

[make commands]

set +x
cp -L -r --no-target-directory "$BUILD_TMPDIR/$INSTALL_PREFIX" "$INSTALLDIR" && find "$INSTALLDIR" -type f -exec touch -r "$BUILD_TMPDIR/$INSTALL_PREFIX" "{}" \;

[content of @postfix_script]

replace_in_files $INSTALLDIR $BUILD_TMPDIR \${EXT_BUILD_DEPS}
replace_in_files $INSTALLDIR $EXT_BUILD_DEPS \${EXT_BUILD_DEPS}
replace_in_files $INSTALLDIR $EXT_BUILD_ROOT \${EXT_BUILD_ROOT}

mkdir -p $EXT_BUILD_ROOT/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/foo/copy_foo/foo

cp -L -r --no-target-directory "$INSTALLDIR" "$EXT_BUILD_ROOT/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/foo/copy_foo/foo" && find "$EXT_BUILD_ROOT/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/foo/copy_foo/foo" -type f -exec touch -r "$INSTALLDIR" "{}" \;

cd $EXT_BUILD_ROOT
```

So it looks quite obvious to me that for some reason `configure_make` doesn't even consider to keep symlinks, turning this into something I have to do outside the Bazel rule (while also possibly polluting the remote cache).

Is there a reason for this? I.e. why shouldn't I create a fork of [`rules_foreign_cc`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc) just to remove this `-L` flag which someone seem to have added intentionally?

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the `rules_foreign_cc` maintainers.

The reason why `rules_foreign_cc` dereferences the symlinks there is because in general the outputs being copied into named outputs may be dangling symlinks as they may not be relative outputs to other build outputs and at least in Bazel 4 which is the minimum version we currently support, dangling symlinks are not allowed as build artifacts. (this behaviour may have changed in later Bazel versions but I'm not 100% sure on this).

What you likely want to actually consume is the `output_group` `gen_dir`. This can be accessed like so:

```
filegroup(
   name = "my_install_tree",
   srcs = [":cmake_target"],
   output_group = "gen_dir",
)
```

The `gen_dir` output group is the entire `install` directory as created by the build artifacts.

Note that you wouldn't actually need to fork the rules to achieve what you were proposing either. The shell script is generated by a toolchain (whose type is currently in the private package and so the right to change this is reserved.) and thus you could provide your own implementation of the toolchain to override the behaviour.

Comment: How would I best use this `filegroup`? Should I then create another `genrule` to copy the content of `my_install_tree` or is there a more direct way to do this?

Comment: Also, are there any examples I can learn from DDG and google are not very encouraging, see https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=%22foreign_cc%22+%22output_group%22++%22gendir%22 :)